# Using environment variables in *.qgs-file

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to use an environment variable in qgis project file (*.qgs)? For example :

```
<datasource>dbname='QBASE' host=10.1.1.1 port=5432 user=USERNAME sslmode=disable key='gid' srid=0 type=MultiPolygon table="public"."geo_zone" (geom) sql=</datasource>
```

I need set value of environment variable "USERNAME" to value of "user".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I am not able to give you an answer to the original question. I cannot think of an idea to work the way you proposed.

I think however that it is possible to solve your problem with a different approach, in particular [pg_service](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-pgservice.html).

In the .qgs file you can connect to the database by means of the `service` parameter. instead of specifying `host`, `port` and `user` individually.

In the .qgs file it should say `service='pg_qbase'` but you can define that from the postgres connection UI in QGIS with the field named service.

While the pg_service.conf file should contain the following

```
[pg_qbase]
host=10.1.1.1
port=5432
user={this part is unique per machine/user}
dbname=QBASE
password=supersecretpassword!
```

If you want to put the password into a separate file, there is also a [.pgpass](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass) file which avoids having to ship passwords in pg_service.conf or the .qgs file.

With this approach you are able to

- define database access rights per user
- while sharing one .qgs project file
- and referencing the same database from multiple .qgs files

Comment: Matthias Kuhn, this good method, but my idea is show form with credentials with typed name. This makes it possible to tape any name besides from pg_service. But thanks, probably I will move on this method.